# How to install YugaByte on Docker for Windows

Tags: docker, yugabytedb

The instructions at https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/quick-start/docker/install/ state that Docker for Windows is supported, however the `yb-docker-ctl` utility  in the step that follows seems to be a *nix app and does not run on Windows 10 Pro. How do I install a 3-node local YugaByte cluster on Docker for Windows? (by the way StackOverflow would not let me add a `YugaByte` tag to the question, I could only add `Docker`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `yb-docker-ctl` utility is actually a Python2 script that will run on Windows 10 Pro if you have Python2 installed. I prefer to use Chocolately (https://chocolatey.org) to manage my package installations, so you could install python2 (not python -- as that will default to python3) using `choco install python2` from PowerShell or CMD. You can also install wget in the same manner.

You will then need to a couple of changes to `yb-docker-ctl`. The script utilizes `os.path.join` which will utilize the Windows default of `\\` for path separator. Add the line `import posixpath` after line 10 of `yb-docker-ctl` and substitute posixpath.join for os.path.join at lines 227 and 377.

After you have made those modifications, you can run `python yb-docker-ctl create` to create your 3 node cluster.

Comment: It worked, thank you. How are you finding Yugabyte in terms of performance/reliability? (it is a relatively new product)